# Android: SocketServer read returning -1 in middle of upload

Tags: android, sockets

I wrote a webserver for android. So yesterday i wanted to add upload capabilities to it.

```
    byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(_client.getInputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);

    int bytesRead = 0;

    while ((bytesRead = bis.read(receivedBuffer,0,BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {

        //do stuff with bytes

        if (bis.available() == 0) {
        break;
        }
    } 
// this point
```

my problem is when i upload files greater than say 400kb read is returning -1 in the middle of the file upload. And if i look at bis.available() at "this point" it is still showing >0

i tried to change

```
bytesRead = bis.read(receivedBuffer,0,BUFFER_SIZE)
```

to this

```
bytesRead = bis.read(receivedBuffer)
```

Another thing i tried was lowering the buffer_size and it worked for a little bit bigger files.Also i added thread.sleep just below if(bis.availabe()==0 and again it helped a little. Its almost like the bis is still loading data from the network stream when i call read and at that point there is nothing and then it returns -1.

I need help its been two days i am trying to get this to work.

Comment: Are you using an OutputStream for the upload? Is this the server code or Android app code?

Comment: Nope i am using a browser with a html form tag. Server code or part there of

Comment: Server Code. But like i said at beginning its a webserver running on android.

Comment: May want to post more of the code, no need to call available from inside the loop - but nothing really wrong here - it's just a loop.

Comment: What i did is i even commented the //do stuff with bytes out completly and still. If i take out available it hangs on last iteration of loop.

Comment: it hangs, even if the loop is empty? there must be something else going on here that you aren't representing in the code you've provided.

Comment: yip it does. Not really there is nothing funky. it a scoket i spawn a accept thread and then i spawn a request thread and in there this code lives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this one. I was prosessing the data so fast that the avaiable method sometimes returned 0 even if there was some data on its way. So i just adding a quick little while that checks if available is 0 and if it is sleep a while(10 ms) and if after a sec it still available ==0 then it breaks out of the while.